Arguments `target` and `output` must have the same rank (ndim) with keras
import pickle
import os
from tf_keras.models import Sequential
from tf_keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Activation, Flatten, Dense
from keras_tuner.tuners import RandomSearch
from keras_tuner.engine.hyperparameters import HyperParameters

# Load data
X = []
y = []
DIRECTORY = 'data'
LOG_DIR = 'log'

for i in range(16):  # Edit number based on how many chunks you have
    with open(os.path.join(DIRECTORY, f'X_chunk_{i}.pickle'), 'rb') as f:
        X_chunk = pickle.load(f)
    with open(os.path.join(DIRECTORY, f'y_chunk_{i}.pickle'), 'rb') as f:
        y_chunk = pickle.load(f)
    
    X.extend(X_chunk)
    y.extend(y_chunk)

X = np.array(X, dtype=np.float32)
y = np.array(y, dtype=np.float32).flatten()

X = X.reshape(-1, 256, 256, 1)

print(len(X))

# Define the model creation function
def create_model(hp):
    model = Sequential()
    
    model.add(Conv2D(
        hp.Int(name='input_units', min_value=32, max_value=256, step=32), 
        (3, 3), 
        input_shape=(256, 256, 1)
    ))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    for i in range(hp.Int(name='n_layers', min_value=1, max_value=4)):  # Adding variation of layers
        model.add(Conv2D(
            hp.Int(name=f'conv_{i}_units', min_value=32, max_value=256, step=32), 
            (3, 3)
        ))
        model.add(Activation('relu'))

    model.add(Flatten()) 
    model.add(Dense(1))  # Change the number of units to 1
    model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))  # Sigmoid for binary classification

    model.compile(
        optimizer="adam",
        loss="binary_crossentropy",  # This is correct for binary classification
        metrics=["accuracy"]
    )
    
    return model

# Define the tuner
tuner = RandomSearch(
    create_model,  # Pass the function itself here
    objective='val_accuracy',
    max_trials=1,  # Number of model variations to test
    executions_per_trial=1,
    directory=LOG_DIR
)

tuner.search_space_summary()

# Search for the best hyperparameters
tuner.search(
    x=X,
    y=y,
    epochs=1,
    batch_size=64,
    validation_split=0.15
)

# Summarize results
tuner.results_summary()


error message:
ValueError: Arguments target and output must have the same rank (ndim). Received: target.shape=(None,), output.shape=(None, 64)

I don't seem to find the issue for why its giving me such message.
My satellite images and im trying to classify whether the are is damaged or not damaged from a hurricane.
I am just preprocessing the data and dividing it into chunks to be able to pickle them
